# Expected output of Birchfield and Tomasi's Pixel Dissimilarity Measure

Tags: pixel, matching, similarity

I'm new to the topic of stereo reconstruction and after a lot of searching, I needed some help.

I'm trying to implement the eSGM algorithm by Heiko Hirschmüller for stereo reconstruction. For the first step (matching cost computation), I'm using the Pixel Dissimilarity measure by Birchfield and Tomasi.

However, I don't think I'm getting the right results. In the first step, I'm just saving the pixel dissimilarity, as calculated by the formula in section 3.1.2 of their [paper](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~tomasi/papers/birchfield/birchfieldTr96.pdf)

I ran my code for a disparity range of 16, and resulting calculations for each disparity. This is what I get for [disparity = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdPWj.png)
 and this for [disparity = 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQo9p.png)

So it just looks like both the images are superimposed and just shift in positions as the disparity increases.

And this is my code for one pixel:

```
/* Using the dissimilarity calculation from Depth Discontinuities by Pixel-to-Pixel Stereo
* published by Stan Birchfield and Carlo Tomasi (Proceedings of the 1998 IEEE International
* Conference on Computer Vision, Bombay, India).
*
* The dissimilarity between pixels xL and xR can be calculated with the following formula:
*
* d = min(d1(xL, xR, il, iR), d1(xR, xL, iR, iL))
*
* where, d1(xL, xR, il, iR) = max(0, iL - iRMax, iRMin - iL)
*    and d1(xR, xL, iR, iL) = max(0, iR - iLMax, iLMin - iR)
*    and iRMax = max(iRMinus, iRPlus, iR)
*    and iRMin = min(iRMinus, iRPlus, iR)
* Similarly, d1(xR, xL, iR, iL) = max(0, iR - iLMax, iLMin - iR)
*    and d1(xL, xR, iL, iR) = max(0, iL - iRMax, iRMin - iL)
*    and iLMax = max(iLMinus, iLPlus, iL)
*    and iLMin = min(iLMinus, iLPlus, iL)
* */

// Variables for the equation
uchar beforeRValue, rValue, afterRValue;
uchar beforeLValue, lValue, afterLValue;
uchar iRMinus, iRPlus, iRMax, iRMin;
uchar iLMinus, iLPlus, iLMax, iLMin;

int row, col, rCol, d;
for (row = 0; row < nRows; ++row)
    for (col = 0; col < nCols; ++col)
        for (d = 0; d < this->disparityRange; ++d)
        {
            // Calculating the equation
            rCol = col - d;
            if (rCol <= 0)
            {
                beforeRValue = this->rightImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[0];
                rValue = this->rightImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[0];
            }
            else {
                beforeRValue = this->rightImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[rCol - 1];
                rValue = this->rightImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[rCol];
            }

            if (rCol == this->leftImage.cols)
                afterRValue = this->rightImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[rCol];
            else
                afterRValue = this->rightImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[rCol + 1];

            iRMinus = (rValue + beforeRValue) / 2;
            iRPlus = (rValue + afterRValue) / 2;
            iRMax = MAX(MAX(rValue, iRMinus), iRPlus);
            iRMin = MIN(MIN(rValue, iRMinus), iRPlus);

            beforeLValue = (col == 0 ? this->leftImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[col] : this->leftImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[col - 1]);
            lValue = this->leftImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[col];
            afterLValue = (col == this->leftImage.cols ? this->leftImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[col] : this->leftImage.ptr<uchar>(row)[col + 1]);

            iLMinus = (lValue + beforeLValue) / 2;
            iLPlus = (lValue + afterLValue) / 2;
            iLMax = MAX(MAX(lValue, iLMinus), iLPlus);
            iLMin = MIN(MIN(lValue, iLMinus), iLPlus);

            costs[row][col][d] = MIN(MAX(MAX(0, lValue - iRMax), iRMin - lValue),
                MAX(MAX(0, rValue - iLMax), iLMin - rValue));
        }
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could please help me understand what/if I'm doing something wrong!

Thank you!

P.S. I'm at first trying to get working code, I don't care about the optimization as of now :)

Comment: Is your goal to get an image of disparities and compare it to the ground truth? The results of Birchfield Tomasi are the dissimilarity for a given disparity. You then need to use those dissimilarities to determine the best disparity (i.e. the disparity for a pixel is the disparity with the lowest dissimilarity).